# Messenger Services in Windows 8.1

Tags: batch-file, cmd, messaging

I was trying to create a CMD Messenger. 
I googled for it, and got a few lines of code.
But the problem is that I a unable to find the Messenger services in Windows 8.1 which I need to start in order to get the Messenger.bat file running.

Can anyone suggest, if the Messenger Service is present in Windows 8.1 or not?
And if it is, then how to start it?

Basically, I need to user `NET SEND` command in CMD. And, I guess, this doesn't works without the Messenger Services.

Comment: What is your use case scenario for needing a pop-up message? Why do you need this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I need to use `NET SEND` command in `CMD`

`net send` was removed in Windows Vista and later, as was the Messenger Service.

It is replaced by `msg`, but only professional and business editions of Windows have the ability to send network messages using `msg`. It is not supported in Windows Home.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [msg](http://ss64.com/nt/msg.html) - Send a pop-up message to a user.
- [Windows Msg command help and faq](https://www.cezeo.com/tips-and-tricks/msg-command/)